# Match statement case int 1 matches with boolean value True

Tags: python, match, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

```
a = True

match a:
    case False:
        print("It is false")
    case 2:
        print('It is 2 true.')
    case 1:
        print('It is 1 true.')

>>> It is 1 true.
```

Why does the program execute the last case statement?

Comment: What does `print(True == 1)` show?

Comment: of course it does. `True == 1` and `isinstance(True, int)` is true. Admittedly, this is a bit of a wart in the Python type system, but "practicality beats purity".

Comment: to clarify: `bool` is a subclass of `int`. So `True==1` and `False==0` (AFAIK).

Comment: Interestingly: `1 == True` is also true. I am curious in this case, my understanding is that `True` is "up-casted" to an `int` value, then compared. So that `1 == 1` returns true. Anyone feel free to correct me if i'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: Booleans don't need to be "upcasted," they are literally integers in Python.